# How to add horizontal scroll to input field for mat-chip-list in Angular?

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material

I've recently started learning Angular & Angular Material and I can't figure out a way to add a scroll bar to an expanding input field for a mat-chip-list. My input field is editable while also using an auto-complete list to populate data. I've tried similar answers that ask you to edit CSS but none of them have worked for me. I need the chips to appear in a single line with a horizontal scroll. Right now, the input field just grows in size to accommodate the chips.

My code snippet:

```
        <!--Keyword section-->
        <mat-form-field class="ranking-chip-list">
          <mat-chip-list #chipList>
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
              (removed)="remove(keyword)">
              {{keyword}}
              <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>

            <input placeholder="Type your keywords to sort resumes..." #keywordInput [formControl]="keywordCtrl"
              [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
              [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" />
          </mat-chip-list>
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let keyword of filteredKeywords | async" [value]="keyword">
              {{keyword}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
        <!--Keyword section ends-->
```

Please let me know if I should also link up the TypeScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just disable flex-wrap for chip-list holder

```
.mat-chip-list-wrapper {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

*please note, if you have some encapsulation in component - you need to use some deep selector or write in styles.scss, maybe thats why CSS solutions you tried wasnt working, cause css is pretty obvious one line solution*

Comment: Thanks very much! I found out what my problem was (apart from not using a .scss file). I just had to do this: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to override styles of child components (found out about it through: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11915)